# What does [Verb Pre-Masu Form] + [shi] do in this context?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-き

I am reading Cardcaptor Sakura in order to practice my comprehension. I see a lot of pre-masu form verbs followed by し, and I am not sure if they are the "giving reasons" し, the "connecting ideas" し, or something else entirely.

Here are some example sentences that I have had trouble with:

> カードに宿{やど}り**し**魔{ま}力{りょく}をこの鍵{かぎ}に移{うつ}し我{われ}に力{ちから}を！
>   (in this sentence, I want to know what the し in 宿{やど}りし does)
>
> 「クロウ」の創{つく}り**し**カードよ
>   (in this sentence I want to know what the し in 創{つく}りし does)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: 「し 」here used as particle meaning "have" or "has", so that 「カードに宿宿りし魔力」means "cards [which] possessed [by] magical powers" and「 クロウの創しカード」means "Clow [who] created [those] cards" (since both of them are past tense).

Comment: ^ Tetsuya, `「カードに宿りし魔力」means "cards [which] possessed [by] magical powers"` <-- Nah. The head noun is **魔力**, not カード.「カードに宿りし**魔力** 」means「[カードに宿った] **魔力** 」, "**magical powers** [which dwelt in the card]" i.e. "**magical powers** [which are possessed by the cards]". `「クロウの創しカード」means "Clow [who] created [those] cards"` <-- Naw, the head noun is **カード**, not クロウ. 「クロウの創りし**カード** 」means「[クロウが作った] **カード** 」, "Cards [that Clow created]". Your translations "cards possessed by magical powers" and "Clow who created those cards" would be 「魔力に宿りしカード/魔力に憑りつかれたカード」 and 「カードを創りしクロウ」.